# Should I throw an exception if using an invalid generic type and if yes, which one?

Tags: c#, exception, generics

I am building a simple custom lightweight *csv* generator class named, oddly enough, `CsvWriter<T>`.

The way this class works is that it will automatically generate a *csv* to an underlying `Stream` from all public properties that are marked with a predefined attribute that we aptly named `CsvPropertyAttribute`.

Upon object creation I would like to check that the generic type implements at least one public property with the predefined `CsvPropertyAttribute`. If that weren' the case I'd like to throw an exception as the generic type parameter is not really valid.

The questions that arise are the following:

1. Is it OK to throw an exception in the constructor? If not the solution would be easy: I could defer the search of valid properties to the first call to `WriteLine(T record)` or similar mehtod (lazy initialization).
2. Is it OK to throw an exception caused by a generic type parameter? Or is it just better to leave the generated `csv` empty? There is no way I can constraint the generic parameter to valid types.
3. And finally, if answer to question No. 2 is yes, what exception should I use? `ArgumentException` seems the better fit but its still not quite right.

Thank you.

Comment: Isn't it better to use type constraints? so like `public interface IMyType<TUser> : where TUser : new, IUser` to constrain them to only putting through a `IUser` interface in my case.

Comment: But my constraint is that as long as the generic tpye has *one* public property with `CsvPropertyAttribute` then the type is valid. I can't constraint that through intercaces.

Comment: @InBetween If your generic argument can't actually support any type, then it's not actually generic.  This is a pretty strong sign that you simply shouldn't be using generics at all.

Comment: @Servy: Well the problem is that there is no way to define the constraint I want. I'm not clear on wether this is a design issue of my classes or a shortcoming of the langue; to be honest generic type parameter constraints are very limited. In this particular case anyhow I wouldn't be able to validly constraint any method argument either even in a non generic solution so I'd still have to throw a runtime exception in the constructor and the code would be a whole lot uglier.

Answer (score 2):

You can even throw an exception from the *class constructor* (aka [*static* constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx)). That way you can do your checks/initializations only once per `T`.

If the class constructor fails for `CsvWriter<Foo>`, you won't be able to even call the constructor of `CsvWriter<Foo>`.

If you're worried about proper argument typing, you could create a custom exception type. It's the cleanest solution. But I wouldn't worry about it that much since if you use the class constructor, your exception will be wrapped in a `TypeInitializationException` either way.

Comment: I like the static constructor idea more than my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is really something that should be a compile-time error, but the language doesn't support it.

1: Yes, go ahead and throw in the constructor.  This fail-fast technique will make it less likely you ship bad code.

2: Throw as soon as possible.  Don't create the file.

3: I'd create a subclass of `InvalidOperationException`.  You may think of something better.

Also, I highly recommend writing a unit test not only for this class, but for any other code that ever instantiates it.

You may also want to re-think your design.  Maybe an interface to give you the basics.